# Scheduling the transmision of frames in RTOS

Tags: c, timer, embedded, rtos, can-bus

I'm planning to use my [STM32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STM32) board to send CAN frames. I implemented a simple scheduler that contains 10 tasks;one task will be responsible to send frames.

To do the job I declared a structure for the CAN frame:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned char data[];
    unsigned char dlc;
    unsigned int timeOfSend  //This is the time in ms in which a frame should be sent
}tFrame;
```

And then I declared a table of the frames to be sent

```
aubFrames[MAX_FRAMES] = {
    {0x12, 0xAABBCC, 4,  100},
    {0x12, 0xAABBCC, 4, 1000},
    {0x12, 0xAABBCC, 4, 2000},
    {0x12, 0xAABBCC, 4, 2010}
};
```

This tell the board to send the first frame after 100 ms, the second after 1000 ms, etc.

**What I actually do:**

I added a new task in the scheduler with a period of 10 ms. This task will check the aubFrames table and if it's time to send a frame it sends the concerned frame, else nothing is to be done. The problem with this solution is that there is a big loss of time. For example, to send the first frame the scheduler access to this task nine times, but with nothing to do.

Is there another solution so that the scheduling will be more effective?

I thought to use a timer interrupt, but I don't think that's the good solution since there are only four timers on the board and the number of frames is more than four, so in my opinion configuring the timers to generate interrupts for different period of time won't work.

Comment: What RTOS are you using?

Comment: Having more frames than timers is irrelevant.  A single timer can do the job.  Set the timer for the first frame, when it fires, reset it for the second frame, and so on.  Not sure if that's how you have it setup already, but (just in case you haven't) it's usually easier to use 'differential' times rather than absolute.  So, instead of each frame having an exact time of msec from the beginning (100, 1000, 2000, 2010) use a 'differential' time from the previous one or 'now' in terms of the timer service routine.  Example: 100, 900, 1000, 10.  Makes job easier and current entry gives next time.

Comment: @kkrambo i designed the OS myself do you have any suggestion about an OS that can be helpful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most RTOSes have a couple of features that seem like they could be appropriate.

One method is for the task to suspend itself for the appropriate amount of time (rather than waking periodically to poll whether it's time). For example, [FreeRTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeRTOS) has the [`vTaskDelay`](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Software-Timer-API-Functions.html) function, which blocks the task for a specified amount of time. Your task knows that it doesn't have to do anything for 100 or 1000 ms so it should delay itself for that amount of time.

Another method is to use a software timer rather than a hardware timer. The RTOS is apparently already getting a periodic tick because it knows to wake your task every 10 ms. It probably also has a software timer service like [this one](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Software-Timer-API-Functions.html) from FreeRTOS. The software timer service is driven by the hardware timer that the RTOS scheduler uses. And it allows you to set up a variety of periodic and single-shot software timers without the need for another hardware timer. Your task could read the `aubFrames` array and setup a one-shot timer for each frame, which expire at the appropriate times. If you don't like the idea of all those software timers running at once then set up the next timer with the previous timer expires.

Comment: Thanks kkrambo for the clarification, i should rather use software timer. i have an extra question : imagine if i have to check if the transmitted frame is acquited (as in TCP/IP) so i should send a frame and wait an amount of time to check if i receive an acquitement. for me i added a callback to the structure tFrame for the checking do you agree with me? ,i think it becomes a little bit complicated, do you have any suggestion or reference that helps me to get out of this problem